# Can I restrict Graph API to be able to share only on Pages and not on Profiles?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

As stated in the question, can anyone point me in the right direction on how to achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can do, While getting a user access token from Graph API, Do not give access to user data permissions.
If you wanted to display only the information of pages just allowed extended permissions(inside user access token). this following will not access your profile but can access for pages.